# Send SMS with GPS location using SMS manager

Tags: android, gps, sms, smsmanager

I need help getting GPS location and sending it via Sms along with the relevant message. I have developed an emergency button app which should send a custom message + GPS location. I am struggling with implementing the GPS location function.

Original code without GPS:
/*This code funtcions well however it does not contain the GPS location*/

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText customMessage;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.customMessage);

    }

    public void sendText(View view)
    {


        String message = "";
        if (view.getId() == R.id.fab)
        {
            message = customMessage.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            Button sender = (Button)view;
            message = sender.getText().toString();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("6505551212", null,message + "(Location Here)", null, null);
    }


}
```

Code with GPS:
/*The problem with the code is that the app just crashes when I click the send button but it has no errors*/

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText customMessage;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.customMessage);

    }

    public void sendText (View view, String phoneNumber, Location currentLocation) {

        String message = "";
        if (view.getId() == R.id.fab)
        {
            message = customMessage.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            Button sender = (Button)view;
            message = sender.getText().toString();
        }


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
        smsBody.append("http://maps.google.com?q=");
        smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLatitude());
        smsBody.append(",");
        smsBody.append(currentLocation.getLongitude());
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("6505551212", null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please post the crash logs. 2. Please make sure you are requesting for location permission at runtime.

Comment: You can try this library: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/README.md on the button click you should trigger the first example from the readme, and then send the sms with accuired gps position

Comment: Log: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-05 12:42:21.711 5063-5063/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5063 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code working because its message length is <=160. But the another message contains url which is larger than 160 characters. To overcome this you need to send message in multiple parts. Use the code given below :
`SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(messageString);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, null, null);`